# Listing contents using UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I am a newbie to iOS programming and I am simply trying to set up a TableView which would populate array contents.
I keep running into the following error.

> uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "BYZ-38-t0r-view-8bC-Xf-vdC" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'

I looked into a couple suggested solutions already but none of them work for my case.

Some suggested that I make my ViewController to be a subclass of UIViewController but I get the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoZgg.png) from doing so.

Another suggested I use UIViewController instead of UITableViewController in my custom class but I get the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKXOv.png) doing so.

My custom class code

```
//
//  AddQuestionTableViewController.swift
//  Quiz Add Question
//
//  Created by Emil Shirima on 7/29/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Emil Shirima. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class AddQuestionTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


var sample = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    sample = ["apple","pear","banana","raspberry"]

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return sample.count
}

// indexPath has info about which section and which row
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("questionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    let data = sample[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = sample[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }    
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return true
}
*/

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
}
```

My ViewController code

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Quiz Add Question
//
//  Created by Emil Shirima on 7/29/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Emil Shirima. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

My current storyboard with hierarchy is found here: //i.stack.imgur.com/2lEVe.png.
Sorry, not enough reputation points to post extra link.

I do have a general idea as to why this is happening but if anyone would explain to me exactly why and how to solve it, I'll sincerely appreciate it.

Comment: Is your delegate and data source hooked up to the class in Storyboard?

Comment: How would I go about checking that? I have linked up table view (including the datastorage and delegate) to the view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Please check ViewController named "AddQuestionTableViewController" on Storyboard.

I think you named "AddQuestionTableViewController" to wrong ViewController (not UITableViewController)

Answer (score 0):

Some common causes for this have to do with Storyboard connections and the Table View Controller file. First, click on the Table View itself in Storyboard and check the Outlets.

[image]

If they are disconnected, drag from the circles in `delegate` and `data source` to the little table view controller icon at the top of the view controller.

Also, make sure your class is hooked up correctly. Go the ID page in storyboard for your Table View *Controller* (NOT the Table itself) and check the class.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error had told you the details: `[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "BYZ-38-t0r-view-8bC-Xf-vdC" nib but didn't get a UITableView.`

You should check your custom UITableView.

Your problem maybe:

1. Your did't set custom UITableView Identity to "BYZ-38-t0r-view-8bC-Xf-vdC" in you xib file. If so, go to `xxx.xib->show identity inspector->Identity` set Restoration Id to "BYZ-38-t0r-view-8bC-Xf-vdC".
2. You've set a xib file's Identity to "BYZ-38-t0r-view-8bC-Xf-vdC", but it's not a UITableView, it's a UIView or something. If so, set the identity to a custom UITableView